# How to remove a non-empty directory with OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I tried to remove a directory using `Sys.remove "mydir"`, but this results in an exception: `Exception: Sys_error u"mydir: Is a directory".`.

Next I looked at `Unix.rmdir "mydir"`, but that did not work because the directory is not empty (it resulted in `Exception: Unix.Unix_error (27, "rmdir", "mydir"`).

So I guess the only way to delete a non-empty directory is to get the list of files in the directory using `Sys.readdir "mydir"`, then delete its contents recursively before finally deleting the empty directory using `Unix.rmdir`.

What is the idiomatic way of removing a non-empty directory using OCaml?

Comment: See 'Removing a Directory and Its Contents' from the [Programming Language Examples Alike Cookbook](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ocaml/directories.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recursively remove its contents first, using `Sys.remove` and `Sys.readdir`, and, once it is empty, remove the directory itself, e.g.,

```
let rec rmrf path = match Sys.is_directory path with
  | true ->
    Sys.readdir path |>
    Array.iter (fun name -> rmrf (Filename.concat path name));
    Unix.rmdir path
  | false -> Sys.remove path
```

Alternatively, you can use the [OCaml Fileutils](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/fileutils/) library, which provides POSIX compliant file utilities, namely the [rm](http://ocaml-fileutils.forge.ocamlcore.org/api-fileutils/FileUtil.html#VALrm) function, that could recursively (and portably) delete the whole directory, e.g.,

```
 FileUtil.rm ~recurse:true [dir]
```

Comment: I've noticed that it's possible to remove a file using `Sys.remove` or `Unix.unlink`. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Theoretically, they use different underlying subsystems, `Sys.remove` is `remove(3)` which is a part of the C89,C99, BSD and POSIX interfaces. While `Unix.unlink` is `unlink(2)`, which belonges to POSIX, SVr4, and BSD. Thus `Sys.remove` is more portable. However, in practice, on popular OSes, the OCaml System Distribution will map both `Unix.unlink` and `Sys.remove` to the same system function, `wunlink` on Windows and `unlink` on Unices.